# AEM query param being removed and CSRF token added

Tags: csrf, aem

My application has a search functionality which uses a query param `fullText` for the search term. But on my QA server, any query parameters are being removed and csrf token is being added.

Example, on homepage, if I search for 'tax', the url should be:

```
https://www.qaserver.com/en/search.html?fullText=tax
```

Instead, it changes to below url and remains on the 'same' page it is on.

```
https://www.qaserver.com/en/home.html?%3Acq_csrf_token=eyJleHAiOjE1MDAyNDk5NzgsImlhdCI6MTUwMDI0OTM3OH0.EXoQy8xeVh3j9kdFdnenLGLl2sFEh_boi_jFareO1is
```

Is there any AEM/dispatcher config missing or incorrect ?

The dispatcher or AEM logs don't show who is appending this param or why.
The same thing happens with direct IP of publish server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Include `<cq:includeClientLib categories="granite.csrf.standalone"/>` on the page from you are making POST ajax or form submit. This should resolve the issue.

Or the other option is to exclude particular servlet path from CSRF Filter Configuration (Which is not recommended).